# CoreData, Defining a model, static data

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an app where I need to maintain an ORM kind of model, and represent an entity ( which has an image, some text fields). The Client wants me to incorporate some of those items of tyoe ( Entity ) in the build of the app, so they should be available there when downloaded, and give the users the ability to download more items. I thought of using Core Data and creating a model. 
My question is : 
1 : Is a good way to go?
2 : If I do this model, and define this entity, can I manually enter the static items of type Entity in Xcode? since they are available locally I don't want to loop over them in a viewdidload method of some UIView!. this is kind of like using SQL Database after defining the table, you can go and enter rows in that DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement the logic (in code) to insert the default Entity objects in your Core Data persistence store, and then execute that logic only if the database is empty at startup. You could add this check to the Xcode-generated app delegate for any Core Data project doing something like this:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }

    // Beginning of code added to Xcode-generated app delegate
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Entity"];
    NSArray *results = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:NULL];
    if ([results count] == 0) {
        // Call method to insert default entities
    }
    // End of code added to Xcode-generated app delegate

    return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

The best approach for inserting default entities depends on how many there are, how likely they are to change, etc. Likewise, the query I included above wouldn't be ideal if there are a lot of entities because I'm fetching them all just to see if there are any. This just gives you an idea of the approach, and would have to be optimized based on specific amounts of data.

Comment: Thnx, that is kind of what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to simply create your application as you would if you were not providing default content. Then run your app in simulator and add some content. Now stop your app, find the data file on your Mac, copy it to your project, and add it to the project resources. Put some code in your app's startup to copy the file from your bundle directory to your documents directory if there isn't one already there.